# Touchpad is behaving very Inaccurate and Jumpy In Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently switched over to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS from Windows 10. After switching over to linux my, touchpad has been behaving very jumpy. It does not feel as accurate as it did in Windows 10. Whenever I move the cursor, its movement is very jittery and inaccurate. However when I use a mouse, the cursor movement seems to be fine and smooth.

Comment: Its 18.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You can check if everything is OK or not: *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Mouse & Touchpad*.

If it's not working again, you should install the specific driver of your device .

and finally, if you want to use touchpad right-click, install GNOME Tweaks.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Open Tweaks and in the Keyboard and Mouse section, and under *Mouse Click Emulation* tick Area.

Comment: I mean the touch pad is working but its movement is very inaccurate. I have the device drivers installed and I checked in settings, everything seems to be as it should be.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in hardware